# Swift UITableView Cell changes image when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a image inside my tableview cells that turns black when the cell is selected as well as the default cell turning gray. Problem is when I scroll down the screen and scroll up again the images are turn back as though they are not selected being image "cellSelected". So, after scrolling selected cells should have the image "cellSelected" yet they have "cellNotSelected". How can I make sure my app remembers the selected cells images?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomerSelectsBusinessesCell
    cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellSelected")

    updateCount()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomerSelectsBusinessesCell
    cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellNotSelected")
    updateCount()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the change of state in your data model somewhere, and then edit your data source methods (specifically cellForRowAtindexPath) to show the cell in its new selected state.

This is true of any change you make to a cell. If the cell scrolls off-screen, it gets recycled and any customizations you've made to it's views will not longer be associated with that indexPath any more. So when the user takes action on a cell, you always need to record the information in your data model.